# Rails server exiting immediately after starting <Undefined method>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a strange issue. I just configured a rails project on a remote server. But immediately after I run 'rails server' command I get this error:

```
[pediatric-nutri]# rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.1.16 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/home/lookwhat/rails_apps/pediatric-nutri/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:5:in `<class:ApplicationController>': undefined method `decent_configuration' for ApplicationController:Class (NoMethodError)
    from /home/lookwhat/rails_apps/pediatric-nutri/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.16/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `load'
```

Comment: Do you have the method `decent_configuration` in `application_controller.rb`?

Comment: Yes. The same copy of code working on local.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps server side updated your `decent_exposure` into a different version of API (V2 to V3). More details on it 
[here](https://github.com/hashrocket/decent_exposure/wiki/Api-changes-in-version-3) particularly in the `Problems you may face upgrading` section.